# Reflected light did not appear

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, reflection

Testing some settings in cylces, tried to set up the same scene in blender, and a different modelling program with different rendering engine.
Cylces did the job well, but cannot achive the yellowish reflection on the bottom plane - which makes the scene more realistic. Any hints?

Thanks!

not cycles
[image: not cycles]

Cycles (no reflection)
[image: cycles]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the max bounces set adequately high to show full global illumination effects. There is a preset that you can activate as well. You may also have to increase the intensity of the light source and adjust the exposure. The distance, size or intensity of the light seems to be different in your first render, because the shadows are much crisper than in the second.

[image: Settings]

Plane with Principled BSDF (Specular 0.5, Roughness 0.5)
[image: Global Illumination]

Plane with Principled BSDF (Specular 0.0, Roughness 0.5)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hints! GI was already set to max with caustics enabled.
Your example looks like the plane has a regular gossyness. (you csn see the shape reflected)
I will try to adjust intensity and exposure!

Comment: @Grey the plane has the default settings of the Principled BSDF, except that the color is darker. The effect is still there when I set specular to zero, although much more diffuse.

Comment: @Grey I have used Filmic as view transform, an HDRI with strength 1.0 (https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=studio&h=studio_small_04) and a sun lamp with strength 5.0

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Did you enable caustics under the Light Paths settings?